# Disable array of days in magento 2 calendar not working on product view page

Tags: magento2, calendar

In my custom Module I am able to disable array of days using this code in `viewproduct.phtml`

```
<script>
require(["jquery", "mage/calendar"], function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
var unavailableDates = ["12-01-2019","19-01-2019","29-01-2019"];
    function unavailable(date) 
{
var string = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy',date);
return [unavailableDates.indexOf(string) == -1];
}

$("#options_4_date").calendar({beforeShowDay: unavailable});

});
});

</script>
```

However I added same code in my Theme `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view.phtml` to work with product options choosing date is not working. [image]

Any Idea or I am not doing it correct.

Here is my theme `view.phtml`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
?>

<?php
    $_config = $this->helper('Magetheme\Custom\Helper\Data');
?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 image-box-detail">
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.media'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 info-box-detail">
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.main'); ?>
        <div class="social-detail">
            <!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-548a6c0340f6f753" async="async"></script>
            <!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
            <div class="share-title"><?php echo __('Share')?></div><div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 detail-bottom-wrapper">
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('detail.bottom'); ?>
    </div>

    <?php
        $related = $block->getChildHtml('related.product');
        $upsell = $block->getChildHtml('upsell.product');
        //var_dump($upsell);
    ?>


    <?php if($_config->getProductDetail('show_related') || $_config->getProductDetail('show_upsell')){?>                
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 box-related-upsell">
        <?php if($_config->getProductDetail('show_related')){?>
            <div class="block product-details box-related">
                <div class="block-title">
                    <strong><?php echo __('Related Products')?></strong>
                </div>
                <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('related.product'); ?>
            </div>
        <?php }?>
        <?php if($_config->getProductDetail('show_upsell')){?>
            <div class="block product-details box-up-sell">
                <div class="block-title">
                    <strong><?php echo __('Upsell Products')?></strong>
                </div>
                <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('upsell.product'); ?>
            </div>
        <?php }?>

    </div>
    <?php } ?>  
</div>
<script>
require(["jquery", "mage/calendar"], function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
var unavailableDates = ["12-01-2019","19-01-2019","29-01-2019"];
    function unavailable(date) 
{
var string = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy',date);
return [unavailableDates.indexOf(string) == -1];
}

$("#options_4_date").calendar({beforeShowDay: unavailable});

});
});

</script>
```

Comment: What error is in the console?

Comment: There no error in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is my solution**

Product Attributes

**Customizable Options** -> Custom options let customers choose the product variations they want.

Instead of selecting **Option Type** As **Date** I selected **Field**.

In the browser I figure out that the **Field Name** is **"options[4]"**

Then in my Theme `view.phtml` I added below code.

```
<script>
require(["jquery", "mage/calendar"], function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
var unavailableDates = ["12-09-2018","19-09-2018","29-09-2018"];
    function unavailable(date) 
{
var string = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy',date);
return [unavailableDates.indexOf(string) == -1];
}

$("input[name='options[4]']").calendar({beforeShowDay: unavailable});

});
});

</script>
```

Wao! it work like charm.

My plugin work on both custom and main store order.

Thank you  [@Herve Tribouilloy](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/29009/herve-tribouilloy) for your response, but your idea didn't cut it.

Comment: np, some days are good, some are not as good, anyway, I have put down a public repository with a self contained plugin that uses my code. Please do comment if it cuts it or not, thanks. see repo at https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/calendar

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I am not sure I am understanding exactly what you are trying to do to be honest..

However, in terms of javascript integration with Magento 2, I think the below may help:

in your phtml, I'd expect options_4_date to be a html element. And in Magento 2, we need the script to be using the json type declaration I put below. the notation "Mbs_TryACalendarInput/js/calendar" means the javascript file location is in a view/frontend/web directory of a module but you can also use a theme location.

```
<div id="options_4_date">
    this is a calendar placeholder
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
      "#options_4_date": {
        "Mbs_TryACalendarInput/js/calendar": {

        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Finally, the below is the translation of your snippet. Unfortunately, I have not tested end to end my script but that should be close to where you want to go

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/calendar'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    var unavailableDates = ["03-09-2018","09-09-2018","11-09-2018"];
    function unavailable(date) {
       var string = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy',date);
       return [unavailableDates.indexOf(string) == -1];
    }

    return function (config, element) {
       $(element).calendar({beforeShowDay: unavailable});
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried it replace jQuery by $ same still not working.

Comment: can you update the post with your phtml code, I am looking at it now

Comment: post updated,  I have added the theme view.phtml

Comment: ok, it does work for me now. good luck

Comment: How do you get it to work i have tried your code is not working.

Comment: you might need to beak it down in small chunks. good luck

Comment: do you still need this to be sorted?